# Proportion of non-zero values by multiple columns/groups

Tags: r, aggregate, proportions

I have a question similar to [Calculate proportion of positives values by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709598/calculate-proportion-of-positives-values-by-group), but for grouping the average fraction by many columns. I'd like to get the proportion of non-zero values in "num" by "Year" and "season". Something that works for n# of columns, no matter where they are in the df in relation to each other.

My data:

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Year  Month   Day Station   num season
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> 
1 2017      1     3     266     4 DRY   
2 2018      1     3     270     2 DRY   
3 2018      1     3     301     1 DRY   
4 2018      1     4     314     0 DRY   
5 2018      2     4     402     0 DRY   
6 2018      1     4     618     0 WET
```

I thought something like this would work, but I get a warning message:

```
> aggregate(df$num>0~df[,c(1,6)],FUN=mean) # Average proportion of num > 0 per year & season

Error in model.frame.default(formula = env_subset$den > 0 ~ env_subset[,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'env_subset[, c(1, 6)]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`, I think this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Year, season) %>%
  summarize(prop_gt_0 = mean(num > 0), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#    Year season prop_gt_0
#   <int> <chr>      <dbl>
# 1  2017 DRY          1  
# 2  2018 DRY          0.5
# 3  2018 WET          0
```

It's usually better to refer to columns by name rather than by number, so, as you say it works *"no matter where they are in the df"*.

You can still use `aggregate`--I prefer the formula interface for working with column names:

```
aggregate(num ~ Year + season, data = df, FUN = \(x) mean(x > 0))
#   Year season num
# 1 2017    DRY 1.0
# 2 2018    DRY 0.5
# 3 2018    WET 0.0
```